# jQuery - How to detect if an item is currently outside of the viewport?

Tags: jquery

I'm building a page that will be using ajax to update a main content area.  Users will be clicking on items from a left hand menu bar to update a div to the right with search results.

I want to detect if a user has scrolled down so far causing the right-hand-side results div to moved outside the viewport -- but has does one detect that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No testing/cross browser assurances/example code but take a look at [`$elem.offset().top`](http://api.jquery.com/offset) vs the [`$(document).scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop) - Might be your solution.

You might need the [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height) of the element and the `window` as well.

Brodingo in #jQuery on freenode just linked me to a [Viewport Selectors plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/viewport) that might simplify it.

Comment: Thanks gnafr! This seem like a pretty tricky problem to solve -- I resorted to using the "viewport selectors" plugin. I'm working on just a prototype at the moment -- if I need to address cross browser issues I may have to open the plugin and borrow some of it's code. Nonetheless ... here's what I did  
if ($("#products-result:in-viewport").length === 0) {
    $.scrollTo('#facet-header', 400);
}

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with the following, where a this_element that is outside of the viewport (either above or below its bounds) triggers YOUR ACTION:

```
function scroll_to(this_element){
    var banner_height = 145;
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
    var element_position = $(this_element).position().top;
    var element_height = $(this_element).height();
    if(((banner_height + element_position) < scroll_position) || ((scroll_position + window_height) < (banner_height + element_position + element_height))){
        //YOUR ACTION        
    }
}
```