# detect div vertical position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so, I have page filled with very large text. text is divided into several sections

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<section id="verypersonalid">chunk of text</section>
<section id="extremlyPersonalId">chunk of text</section>
<section id="heavilyPersonalId">chunk of text</section>
</div>
```

and my intention is every time section leaves viewport to fire some event  / execute function

Comment: You probably looking for $(window).scroll and $(window).scrollTop ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726030/jquery-how-to-detect-if-an-item-is-currently-outside-of-the-viewport

Comment: maybe yes - maybe no. gotta check out API

Comment: This post have an interesting solution that might help: http://www.benknowscode.com/2013/07/detect-dom-element-scrolled-with-jquery.html